How do I toggle the "-> void" in godot's GDScript?
A while ago I turned on a setting that enabled Godot to automatically add -> void into new functions.  Here is an example:
func _ready() -> void:
    pass 

I would like to turn this off and just get this instead:
func _ready():
    pass 

If anyone knows where this setting is, it would be a great help to me.

I SOLVED IT!

Click on the "Editor" menu at the top of Godot, and select "Editor Settings..."
Under "Text Editor", click on "Completion"
Then, toggle on or off "Add Type Hints"

You should be good to go! :)
